# Android service does not start properly

Tags: android, service, background

I implemented everything I've found here, but my service is not starting yet.

What I need to do is to start playing a radio station when the user clicks on a button, and only stop it when he clicks it again. I don't want the radio to be stopped if the application get closed.

When I test the code I'm sending, nothing happens.

Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".RadioService"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="false"
>
</service>
```

Service Code:

```
package com.po.portelaonline.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

    public class RadioService extends Service {

    Player player;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        player = new Player();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        player.stopThread();
    }

    }
```

Player class code:

```
package com.po.portelaonline.service;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;

import com.po.portelaonline.classes.Util;

class Player extends Thread {

volatile boolean running = true;

@Override
public void run() {

    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        player.setDataSource(Util.getRadioUrl());
        player.setOnPreparedListener(oplPlayer);
        player.prepareAsync();

        while (running) {
            Player.sleep(500);
        }

        player.release();
        player = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void stopThread() {
    running = false;
}

OnPreparedListener oplPlayer = new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
};

}
```

And I'm calling this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RadioService.class);
if(getApplicationContext().startService(i) == null){
findViewById(R.id.btnPlayStop).setBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop));
}else{
getApplicationContext().stopService(i);
findViewById(R.id.btnPlayStop).setBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for service class.

You don't need to create MediaPlayer object in separate thread. `player.prepareAsync();` is already asynchronous.

**EDIT**:

The path to the RadioService class into the AndroidManifest.xml should be absolute: `android:name="com.po.portelaonline.service.RadioService"`

```
public class RadioService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener{

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startPlayer();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        initMediaPlayer();
    }


    private void initMediaPlayer () {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    }

    private void startPlayer(){
        player.setDataSource(Util.getRadioUrl());
        player.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        mPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared (MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError (MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e("RadioService OnError", "what="+what+" extra="+extra);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Had thought about doing this way after posting. Still not working. When I click the button nothing happens, eve the LogCat doesn't displays anything...

Comment: even when I put Log.e on onCreate, onStartCommand an onDestroy, nothing apperas on LogCat

Comment: I suppose the Service doesn't start. Try to set in AndroidManifest.xml full path to the RadioService class: android:name="com.po.portelaonline.service.RadioService" It may help.

Comment: Just one detail: Without using a new Thread, it throws NetworkOnMainThreadException. That's the reason why I've put it on a thread. Remembered it just now

Comment: I think there are some network operations into Util.getRadioUrl() method. Because when you pass just a String to the setDataSource() it should be OK.

Comment: Yes, I get the Url from a WebService. But even passing a String it throws the exception. Rolled back the changes you suggested on the Service and now I'm usin the Player class again. The prtoblem with the service was ony the name. I'ts fully functional now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

i guess  it should be 
`if(getApplicationContext().startService(i) != null)`
instead of `if(getApplicationContext().startService(i) == null)`

You are immediately stopping the service after you start it.

Comment: from the doc for startService
If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned.

Comment: That's the point: if the service does not exist it does mean that i have clicked on play, but if it already exists I'm clicking on stop, I'm using the same button for both actions